# Which component is anchor when aligning in KiCad layout?

Tags: kicad

I simply can not figure out the logic behind which component moves and which one is used as the anchor when using the align functions in the KiCad layout. Is there something I'm missing?
What about when aligning multiple components at the same time?

Comment: Which version?  We've had eight updates so far this year: https://www.kicad.org/blog/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your mouse over an item when aligning, that is your anchor.  Otherwise, it is the left most/right most/top most/bottom most element